# Inner join only with TABLES declaration

Tags: abap, opensql

I need to write a ABAP program using an inner join on the tables mara and makt. I understand the idea of using data declarations like this:

```
data: imatnr type mara-matnr,
      ematnr type makt-matnr.

select mara~matnr makt~matnr into (imatnr, ematnr) from mara left join makt on mara~matnr = makt~matnr.
  write: / imatnr, ematnr.
endselect.
```

In my exams I have to write a ABAP program without internal tables, field symbols  **JUST TABLES DEKLARATIONS**.
I made several attempts to do this but I found no answer. 
I tried something like this:

```
tables: mara, makt.


select * from mara inner join makt on mara~matnr = makt~matnr.
  write: / mara-matnr, makt-matnr.
endselect.
```

The console says that I have to use an INTO if I want to use an JOIN within a select * from statement.

So my question is: Is it possible to build an JOIN only with `TABLES` or do I need `DATA:` anyways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is:
>
> Is it possible to build an JOIN only with tables: mara, makt.

No.
Table is a work area aka flat structure, keyword is **flat**. You cannot select multiple rows only with TABLES and cannot join TABLES workareas.

BTW, TABLES [help guidelines](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abaptables.htm) clearly says

> No table work areas except for classic dynpros

so forget this obsolete stuff.

If your exams and your learning courses require you to use only `TABLES` then run away from those course and those school. Please, run away.

P.S. The only way you can fulfill your nasty requirement is nested SELECTs:

```
TABLES: mara, makt.

SELECT * FROM mara
  INTO mara.
  WRITE: / `MARA selected: `, mara-matnr.
  SELECT *
    INTO makt
    FROM makt WHERE matnr = mara-matnr.
    WRITE: / `MAKT selected: `, makt-matnr.
  ENDSELECT.
ENDSELECT.
```

But that feels disgusting.

Comment: I love this answer, although I believe the original question (the exam's) has been misunderstood.
Can you add to your answer the chance to use table-type declarations?

Comment: No such chance. The one (and only!) acceptable use-case for `TABLES` is classic dynpros, which is not the case here.

Comment: Nonono... I couldn't express it properly... 
I meant DATA: begin of line, itab like table of
I'd never ask (nor permit under my watch) the use of the TABLES sentence.

Comment: You're right... he/she definitively must run away from that place *shiver*

Answer (score 2):

Few distinctions between SQL selection queries that might help you.

A generic select statement (without any particular type) looks like this.

```
Select * from [table] where [field] = [value]
```

Depending on whether or not and how you specify `into` clause a certain type of select is used.

---

## `into table`

`into table` selects one or multiple records **into internal table**. can only be used when your select clause (field list) is **identical** to structure of your internal table.

```
   data: lt_ekko type table of ekko,
         ls_ekko type table of ekko,
   select * from ekko into table @lt_ekko.
   loop at lt_ekko into ls_ekko.
      write: / ls_ekko-ebeln.
   endloop.
```

---

## `into`

`into` means you are selecting into a variable (if you are selecting 1 column) or a structure (if you are selecting more than 1). This is important, because structures can only and variables only store 1 value or row, which means you must **specify that you are selecting a `single` row** or use `select`/`endselect` statements to perform looping select.

```
  data: ls_ekko type ekko.
  select single * from ekko into @ls_ekko where ebeln = [some number]
  write: / ls_ekko-ebeln.
```

OR

```
    select * from ekko into @ls_ekko where ebeln = [some number].
       write: / ls_ekko-ebeln. "will print one for each row
    endselect.
```

---

## `into corresponding fields of (table)`

`into corresponding fields of` (and `into corresponding fields of table`) selects records the same way `into` and `into internal table`. The difference is that your structure or internal table does not have to be identical to your selected field list. Selected fields will be stored into your table/structure fields with same names.

```
  data: ls_ekko type ekko.
  select single ebeln, bukrs from ekko into @ls_ekko where ebeln = [some number].
  write: / ls_ekko-ebeln.
```

---

## **no `into` clause**

**no `into` clause** is similar to `into` [structure], because it can only select 1 record. That means you have to specify that you select a `single` record. 
Note: Tables you are selecting from must be declared in the program to use this type of select.

```
  select single * from ekko where ebeln = [some number].
  write: / ekko-ebeln.
```

---

Since you are not using `into` clause, you are using the last type, and that means you must use `select single`